# What does the term pass mean in python?

Tags: python

What does pass mean in python? I have seen it used and I do not see why you need to use it or what it does? I guess I could say it passes over whatever function it is in, but why include it?

Comment: it is the same as a NOOP instruction in other languages ... and you largely include it for the same reasons

Comment: read some python books or google fu

Answer (score 4):

Quoth [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements):

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

Answer (score 1):

"It is used when a statement is required syntactically but you do not want any command or code to execute.

The pass statement is a null operation; nothing happens when it executes. The pass is also useful in places where your code will eventually go, but has not been written yet (e.g., in stubs for example):" 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm